# Database deployment using QSR (Quest Script Runner) is slow

Tags: oracle, toad

As part of the automatic deployment of a project, we deploy various Oracle scripts (packages, tables, data, etc...) using `qsr` - Quest Script Runner that is part of [Toad](http://www.quest.com/Toad/Oracle). The script executes multiple sql files using the following syntax:

```
qsr -c "user/pass@server" -f "file.sql" -o "log.txt" -e
```

The problem is that we have around 100 sql files that we need to deploy on 8 environments. And each sql file execution takes approx. 1-2 seconds, even if it's a simple file or a simple check (if table exists, skip, else create it). And because of this sometimes the deployment can take 30 minutes or more.

I checked the only documentation I could find in the Help section of Toad and tried the -i parameter and also removing the -e parameter:

[image]

I see some improvement, mostly because of the `-i` parameter, but I am just worried what removing `-e` parameter really does. Are the scripts stacked then in QSR? When is QSR closed on the deployment agent (the running machine)?

Also, I am a bit puzzled that I cannot find any documentation online about this tool, so any help on how to speed this deployment up would be appreciate (I have already tried [sqlplus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b12170/qstart.htm) as an alternative, but it seems our scripts are not 100% compatible with it - some of them are simply not executed).

Comment: Why are you not cloning a "golden copy" with `RMAN`?

Comment: @MichaelKutz As far as I know, RMAN does physical restoration by overwriting your data with old one. Can it be used to publish only schema updates (let's say, add a new column to a table)?

Answer (score 0):

For "Schema Updates", look at *Edition Based Redefinition*.  You might also want to check out 12.2's *Application Container*.